How to verify no side effects from added code in C++?
I am currently working on a C++ project where I've introduced some new code to extend its functionality. However, it is very important to ensure that this new code does not introduce any side effects to the existing system.
Could anyone guide me on the best practices or methods to verify that the added code does not cause any unintended side effects? How would one do this? I was thinking about static analysis methods for data or control flow analysis.
Any advice, tools, or references to documentation would be greatly appreciated.

I'd guess that the best you can do in practice, in most situations, is manual code review.
In most cases, static analysis is unlikely to be effective at evaluating risks that (1) the new code uses up too much CPU/compute/memory/disk space, causing the rest of the system to slow down, (2) the new code inadvertently modifies parts of the filesystem/registry/etc. that affects the rest of the system, (3) (in a multi-threaded application) the new code causes concurrency issues, (4) the new code introduces a security vulnerability, buffer overrun bug, etc., that can be exploited to take control of the rest of the system.
There are many possible techniques using static analysis or code verification, but they will tend to reason more about side effects at the programming language level and less about impact at the systems level (such as risks I highlighted above).
